How to Accurately Calculate CPU Usage Percentage for Each Worker in a Clustered Node.js Application?
I'm running a clustered Node.js application and trying to monitor the CPU usage percentage for each individual worker process. I'm using the cluster module to fully utilize a multi-core server, with around 8 worker processes handling requests.
My goal is to track each worker's CPU usage as a percentage so I can see how much CPU each worker consumes over time.
What I’ve Tried
I initially set up a Gauge metric using the prom-client library to expose metrics for Prometheus and Grafana. My approach was to:

Use process.cpuUsage() in each worker to get the CPU usage in microseconds.
Calculate the difference in CPU usage over an interval.
Attempt to convert this to a CPU usage percentage,factoring in the number of available cores.

Here’s the relevant part of the code I’m using to calculate CPU usage percentage:
import http from 'http';
import cluster from 'cluster';
import os from 'os';
import { app, startApolloServer } from './app.js';
import prisma from './prisma/index.js';
import 'dotenv/config';
import { handleUncaughtErrors } from './middleware/errorHandlerMiddleware.js';
import client from 'prom-client';

const SERVER_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const numWorkers = parseInt(process.env.WORKER_COUNT || `${Math.max(1, Math.floor(os.cpus().length / 2))}`, 10);
console.log(`Number of workers: ${numWorkers}`);

// Initialize Prometheus metrics collection for each worker
client.collectDefaultMetrics();

// Gauge metric for manual per-worker CPU usage tracking
const cpuUsageGauge = new client.Gauge({
  name: 'nodejs_worker_cpu_usage',
  help: 'CPU usage percentage of each Node.js worker',
  labelNames: ['worker_id'], // Add worker ID as a label
});

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  console.info(`Primary ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Listen for dying workers and restart them.
  cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
    console.warn(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died. Starting a new one...`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  const startServer = async () => {
    try {
      const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
      await startApolloServer(app);

      httpServer.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
        console.info(` Worker ${process.pid} started at http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}/graphql`);
      });

      handleUncaughtErrors(httpServer, prisma);

      // Set up CPU usage monitoring
      let previousCpuUsage = process.cpuUsage();
      const availableCores = os.cpus().length;

      setInterval(() => {
        const currentCpuUsage = process.cpuUsage();
        const userTime = currentCpuUsage.user - previousCpuUsage.user;
        const systemTime = currentCpuUsage.system - previousCpuUsage.system;
        const totalCpuTime = userTime + systemTime;

        // Convert to percentage: use interval time and number of cores
        const usagePercent = (totalCpuTime / (5e6 * availableCores)) * 100;

        // Update the gauge metric for this worker
        cpuUsageGauge.set({ worker_id: process.pid.toString() }, usagePercent);

        // Store current CPU usage for the next interval comparison
        previousCpuUsage = currentCpuUsage;
      }, 5000);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to start server', error);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  };

  startServer().catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to start server', error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  // Gracefully close Prisma connection on app exit
  process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} received SIGTERM, shutting down gracefully...`);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(0);
  });

  process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} received SIGINT, shutting down gracefully...`);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(0);
  });
}

The Problem
The results I’m seeing in Grafana don’t align with what I expect based on other CPU usage metrics (e.g., Docker stats). Sometimes, I see extremely low values (under 1%), and other times values seem inflated.
What I Need
How can I accurately calculate the CPU usage percentage for each worker in a clustered Node.js setup, taking into account multiple CPU cores? Ideally, I’d like to see each worker’s CPU usage as a clear percentage, similar to what you’d see in Docker stats but per-worker in Node.js.
Any help or clarification on how to correctly calculate this would be appreciated!

prom-client + cluster module
According to the doc, to use prom-client with the cluster module, you should replace the default global registry with the aggregated registry:

Metrics are aggregated from the global registry by default. To use a different registry, call client.AggregatorRegistry.setRegistries(registryOrArrayOfRegistries) from the worker processes.

You could treat it this way - each worker exposes its own map with the metrics, and to collect them from the single "app" you should combine them all. Here is the example suggested by the doc.
prom-client's default metrics
There are some basic metrics collected by the prom-client lib by default, including the process.cpuUsage(), consider to check them if they fits your needs. Most likely this is what you want.

I will do that and will update you soon. Thanks for the comment.
